# How can I solve the problem that no DNS request occured after proxychains' file setup?

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, ip-address, proxychains

May i know how to solve the problem that make DNS request occur? Thanks a lot!

**Below is the command that i have typed in**

```
guee@Kali:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done         
guee@Kali:~$ sudo apt-get install tor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
tor is already the newest version (0.4.4.5-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1294 not upgraded.
guee@Kali:~$ sudo vi /etc/proxychains.conf
guee@Kali:~$ sudo service tor start
guee@Kali:~$ proxychains firefox google.com
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
guee@Kali:~$
```

**Here is the proxychains configuration file**

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and use the format buttons to format your console commands and output. Also do not include images of config files. If you exclude the comments, it is just 5 lines of a config file. Copy-paste these lines as text and format them.

Comment: Hi sir, I am really sorry about that as I am new in this community. Regarding the config files part, i have to say sorry again because I am not able to copy and paste the content of the config files.